# How to create setup file

Tags: c#, mysql, installation

I developed a c# windows form application with a MySQL database.

I follow the following steps when I install the application on clients machines.

1. I install MySQL server.
2. I upload manually the database of my application to the MySQL server.
3. I run my C# application.

I need to pack all the 3 steps on one setup file which install the MySQL server and upload the database and then the user can run the C# application.

Comment: A great place to start is https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/307353

Answer (score 0):

Over the years I have used a few installbuilders, and feel pretty happy with the one I am currently using: [WiX](http://wixtoolset.org/).

If you want a pure .msi-based solution, then WiX is it. Especially if the MySQL guys have a msi merge module (.msm) available that you can merge with your installer.

The downside of WiX is that you are forced to focus on the finer details of things. The upside is that you can focus on the finer details. The learning curve is a bit steep, but once you have your initial installer going it won't require much maintenance and it integrates neatly with your Visual Studio solution file. msbuild and tfs support out of the box (just remember to install WiX on your build server).